# How to create a writer for a String in Go

Tags: go

I need to use the [*template.Execute](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) method but I want the result as a string or byte[] so that I can pass it to another [*template.Execute](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) but the method writes its results to a writer. Is there a way to create a writer that will write to a variable I define?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use an instance of [`bytes.Buffer`](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer), which implements `io.Writer`:

```
var buff bytes.Buffer
if err := tpl.Execute(&buff, data); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

You can then get a `string` result using [`buff.String()`](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer.String), or a `[]byte` result using [`buff.Bytes()`](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer.Bytes).

Comment: ...  `tpl.Execute(io.Writer(&buff), data);` ...

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `strings.Builder` for this purpose:

```
package main

import (
   "html/template"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   t, e := template.New("date").Parse("<p>{{ .month }} - {{ .day }}</p>")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   b := new(strings.Builder)
   t.Execute(b, map[string]int{"month": 12, "day": 31})
   println(b.String())
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strings#Builder